# Building a large-ish grid of nodes in SpriteKit with reasonable performance

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

**Update:** using bg2b's solution fixed the problem. The [resulting code can be seen here](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/Spriteoscope) (hmmm, need to add a readme).

I came across some articles on an [old demoware known as Kalidescope](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25304/anyone-up-for-decompiling-some-8080-code-for-kaleidoscope). It consists of a grid of 64 x 64 pixels, corresponding to the natural resolution of the [Dazzler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cromemco_Dazzler), to create a 4-way kalidescope-like pattern. It's really quite amazing for 127 bytes.

I thought I'd recreate it on xOS using SpriteKit for funzies. Make 64 x 64 SKShapeNode(rectOf...)s of an appropriately enlarged size, in this case, 16x16, and `.position` them to tile out the SKScene. To run the loop, select one of the nodes and change its color, and then the same for the three similar nodes mirrored across the axes.

Well, it works... at 2 fps. I am a bit surprised by this. Sure, it's a lot of nodes, but only four are changed per loop and all that changes is the color. The rest are doing nothing. In fact, you don't even have to do the animation, simply setting them up causes the issue, as in the code below.

I'm guessing that I am forgetting something in the setup to tell the Scene that the nodes are not "active" and should be normally ignored? Or is this number of nodes simply beyond SK? It does not seem *that* large.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let numColumns = 64
    let numRows = 64
    let pixelSize = min(self.size.width / Double(numColumns), self.size.height / Double(numRows))
    
    // now create a series of SKNodes to represent the pixels
    for row in 0..<numRows {
      for col in 0..<numColumns {
        // make a new node and set it to the background color
        let n = SKShapeNode.init(rectOf: CGSize.init(width: pixelSize, height: pixelSize), cornerRadius:0)
        n.fillColor = NSColor.red
        n.strokeColor = NSColor.black
        
        // our screen is -size.width/2...size.width/2, the original is numColumns, so convert
        let xloc = pixelSize * Double(col - (numColumns / 2)) + 8
        let yloc = pixelSize * Double(row - (numRows / 2)) + 8
        n.position = CGPoint.init(x:xloc, y:yloc)
        
        // and add them to the scene
        self.addChild(n)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Shape nodes in SpriteKit perform poorly.  Use `SKSpriteNode`.  Or if you don't want to make images for them, use shape nodes and render them to a texture, then use sprite nodes based on the texture.

Comment: So SpriteNode instead of ShapeNode? Ok I will try that.

Comment: @bg2b - WOW! You're not kidding about the performance difference! >5k shapes and 60 fps, up from <1. If you make this an answer I will select it. BTW, any idea why it would be so different? I suspect it's drawing all paths every update even though they are not changed?

Comment: Probably. Apple mentions this in the [Getting Started with Shape Nodes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skshapenode/getting_started_with_shape_nodes) document: "*However, the SKSpriteNode class offers higher performance than this class, so use shape nodes sparingly.*"

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicate, using `SKShapeNode` is much slower than `SKSpriteNode`.  I don't know what the shape nodes are doing internally, but sprite nodes correspond pretty closely to what GPUs support, so it makes sense that they're fast.

If you want to turn shape nodes into sprite nodes (e.g., you don't want to produce images of the shapes), you can try making shape nodes and rendering them to a texture: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/creating_a_new_node_by_rendering_to_a_texture

Comment: This should be selected as the answer. :)